# how to sort the csv items based on a particular field in freemarker?

Tags: freemarker, smooks

Name,RollNo,Height,Weight
Adam,10,160,52
Andrew,11,152,40
Brad,12,162,55
Bran,13,161,53

In this case i need to sort the rows based on the Height field. Can you please suggest your answers?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how Smooks expose the CSV to the template. If it's a list of rows, where you can read cells in a row like `row.Height` (like `<#list myCsv as row>${row.Height}</#list>`), then `myCsv?sort_by('Height')` should work.

Note however that in general such things should be done outside the template. For more complex cases (even with sorting by multiple fields) you will run into limitations quickly.